# How can I remove duplicate rows and calculate their frequency?

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame`

```
ID  code
A    1
A    1
A    2
A    1
B    4
B    1
B    1
C    2
C    3
C    3
C    2
```

I know how to do removing，but I have to calculate the frequency:

```
ID  code  freq
A    1     3
A    2     1
B    4     1
B    1     2
C    2     2
C    3     2
```

Comment: Another way: `cbind(unique(df), freq = na.omit(as.vector(tapply(df$code, list(df$code, df$ID), length))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways. Here is one using `ave`:

```
unique(within(mydf, {
  Freq <- ave(code, ID, code, FUN = length)
}))
#   ID code Freq
# 1  A    1    3
# 3  A    2    1
# 5  B    4    1
# 6  B    1    2
# 8  C    2    2
# 9  C    3    2
```

Or, another option (but the row orders are different):

```
X <- data.frame(table(mydf))
X[X$Freq != 0, ]
#    ID code Freq
# 1   A    1    3
# 2   B    1    2
# 4   A    2    1
# 6   C    2    2
# 9   C    3    2
# 11  B    4    1
```

---

#### Update

If you are willing to use packages (the two other options in this answer use base R), you should check out "data.table", particularly if your data are large:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(mydf)
DT[, .N, by = c("ID", "code")]
#    ID code N
# 1:  A    1 3
# 2:  A    2 1
# 3:  B    4 1
# 4:  B    1 2
# 5:  C    2 2
# 6:  C    3 2
```

---

#### Benchmarks

Here are some benchmarks on a larger dataset, to see how the options scale.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
```

Make up some data:

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(ID = sample(LETTERS, 100000, replace = TRUE), 
                   code = sample(1:10, 100000, replace = TRUE))
DT <- data.table(mydf)
```

Establish your functions:

```
AM1 <- function() {
  X <- data.frame(table(mydf))
  X[X$Freq != 0, ]
}

AM2 <- function() {
  unique(within(mydf, {
    Freq <- ave(code, ID, code, FUN = length)
  }))
}

AM3 <- function() {
  DT[, .N, by = c("ID", "code")]
}

DDP <- function() {
  ddply(mydf, .(ID, code), nrow)
}
```

Benchmark:

```
microbenchmark(AM1(), AM2(), AM3(), DDP(), times=100)
# Unit: milliseconds
#   expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
# AM1()  65.64750  66.92666  68.86916  70.25277 137.12961   100
# AM2() 224.85660 228.05091 230.02311 232.77116 295.55184   100
# AM3()  11.15789  11.30541  11.44706  11.72064  77.72398   100
# DDP()  97.75484 100.86891 103.42602 106.85045 171.02863   100
```

On small datasets (you can try it out), `AM2()` should be the fastest, but it doesn't scale well, as can be seen in the results above. `AM3()`, however, (the "data.table" option) is going to be hard to with larger datasets.

Comment: By the way, if you set a key when creating your `data.table`, your speeds would be even better!

Answer (score 2):

Use `ddply` from the `plyr` package.

```
library(plyr)
dfDuplicates = as.data.frame(read.table(textConnection("ID  code
A    1
A    1
A    2
A    1
B    4
B    1
B    1
C    2
C    3
C    3
C    2"), header = TRUE))

ddply(dfDuplicates, .(ID, code), nrow)
```